# makefile skips making the build directory

Tags: makefile

I want all my build files stored in a `build` directory inside the project root folder.  Though, I don't want to have to rebuild all of the files if I add a debug flag.  Thus, I have two directories `.build_release` and `.build_debug`.  Then I make a symbolic link from `build` to the proper directory.

I want all of this to be handled by `make`.  Here is my makefile:

```
## setup

ifdef DEBUG
BUILDDIR=.build_debug
else
BUILDDIR=.build_release
endif

BLACKLIST:=bayesP obsDataStats test3 test bayesPsamplesBR test2 tuneSp \
toyFeatures2Multi getCov getDist isConnected mergeClusters sample \
toyFeatures0 toyFeatures1 toyFeatures2 toyFeatures3 toyFeatures4 \
toyFeatures6 toyFeatures7 wnsFeatures0 wnsFeatures1 wnsFeatures2

## make code

PROGS:=$(shell find ./src/ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.cpp" -exec grep -l "int main" {} \;)
PROGS:=$(notdir $(basename $(PROGS)))
PROGS:=$(filter-out $(BLACKLIST),$(PROGS))

CPP_SRC:=$(wildcard src/*.cpp)
CPP_SRC:=$(notdir $(basename $(CPP_SRC)))
CPP_SRC:=$(filter-out $(PROGS) $(BLACKLIST),$(CPP_SRC))

PROGS:=$(PROGS:=.bin)
PROGS:=$(PROGS:%=$(BUILDDIR)/%)

CPP_SRC:=$(CPP_SRC:%=src/%.cpp)
CPP_OBJ:=$(CPP_SRC:src/%.cpp=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)

LIB=$(BUILDDIR)/libspatialDecisionMaking.so

## test code

CPP_SRC_TEST:=$(wildcard src/test/*.cpp)
CPP_SRC_TEST:=$(notdir $(basename $(CPP_SRC_TEST)))
CPP_SRC_TEST:=$(filter-out $(BLACKLIST),$(CPP_SRC_TEST))

PROGS_TEST:=$(CPP_SRC_TEST:%=$(BUILDDIR)/test/%.bin)

CPP_OBJ_TEST:=$(CPP_SRC_TEST:%=$(BUILDDIR)/test/%.o)

CPP_SRC_TEST:=$(CPP_SRC_TEST:%=src/test/%)

## options

CC=g++-4.9

ifdef DEBUG
CPP_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -ggdb
else
CPP_FLAGS=-std=c++11 -O3
endif
LD_FLAGS=-Isrc -L$(BUILDDIR) -lgsl -larmadillo -fPIC -fopenmp

## rules

all: | $(BUILDDIR) $(LIB) $(PROGS) build

test: | $(BUILDDIR)/test $(LIB) $(PROGS_TEST) build

build: $(BUILDDIR)
    ln -rfs $(BUILDDIR) build

$(BUILDDIR)/test: $(BUILDDIR)
    mkdir $(BUILDDIR)/test

$(BUILDDIR):
    mkdir $(BUILDDIR)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.bin: src/%.cpp $(LIB)
    $(CC) $(CPP_FLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LD_FLAGS) -l$(LIB:$(BUILDDIR)/lib%.so=%)
    ln -rfs $@ $(@:%.bin=%)

$(LIB): $(CPP_OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CPP_FLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LD_FLAGS) -shared

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp $(BUILDDIR)/%.d
    $(CC) $(CPP_FLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(LD_FLAGS)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.d: src/%.cpp
    $(CC) $(CPP_FLAGS) -MM $< -MT $(@:%.d=%.o) > $@ $(LD_FLAGS)

%.cpp:

%.hpp:


# include dependencies
-include $(CPP_OBJ:%.o=%.d)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)
```

Though, it seems to skip making `$(BUILDDIR)`.  I delete the directories before I run make every time and it goes directly to building the dependency makefiles based on the rules for target `$(BUILDDIR)/%.d`.  However, it naturally complains when trying to build the dependencies because `$(BUILDDIR)` doesn't exist.

Any ideas why it would be skipping the recipe for making `$(BUILDDIR)`?

Comment: The build directory exists, and is up to date according to the dependencies listed for it (none), so `make` correctly infers there is nothing for it to do and doesn't do anything.  If the directory doesn't exist, it will create the directory; then it is done.  I may be missing something, but that's my immediate take on it.

Comment: That's what I understand too. But I explicitly delete the directories before running and it still skips the recipe for the build directory.

Comment: So it doesn't create the directory, or it doesn't do anything about putting stuff in the directory?

Comment: Both. It skips making the directory. And then complains when it tries to put anything in the directory for the obvious reason that it doesn't exist haha.

Comment: Lemme think a bit.  Can I observe that you've created an example that isn't very much an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You could probably show the problem without the black-list, for example, and maybe without the tests, etc. — which would then make it easier for people to emulate your environment.

Comment: I had to do a bit more surgery on it than this (the `-r` option to `ln` is not portable, for example, and the list of libraries that I don't have had to be neutered, and …), but changing the line: `all: | $(BUILDDIR) $(LIB) $(PROGS) build` to
`all: | build $(BUILDDIR) $(LIB) $(PROGS)` seems to resolve the problem.  Targets are built left-to-right, so putting `build` first (which should be tagged `.PHONY: build`) makes sure that it done before much else happens.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I haven't created a MCVE.  I will work on this.  I tried your solution, but still haven't the same issue.  It eventually creates the directory, but it is the last thing it does.  It first tries to build the dependency files (complains since the directory is not there), then the final action is creating the directory.  Thus if I run it a second time, it will run fine.  But this should not need to be run twice.  I'm quite confused as to why it "does not seem" to be building left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have one more question on SO than answers, so I had to find a question to answer :) , and you seemed to not like the answer that was already there, so OK, even though your question was not "minimal", I spent an hour to work on it.

Your Makefile is not bad generally, but it does not follow a number of "good practices".  Once I tidied everything up, all the problems disappeared.  I hope it helps you to learn from this example - how I changed your original makefile to follow good practices.

The only little problem left, is that `build` is always relinked every time.  This is because normally Make does not "depend" on variable values (such as `DEBUG`), only on files.  It is possible to fix that (in this small case it does not matter much, but maybe later you will need this solution), by creating "dependable variables".  See my answer at

[How do I force a target to be rebuilt if a variable is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145267/how-do-i-force-a-target-to-be-rebuilt-if-a-variable-is-set/26147844#26147844)

Below is the complete working makefile, I put comments on changes outside the code.

```
## setup
```

use `:=` when you can

```
ifdef DEBUG
BUILDDIR:=.build_debug
else
BUILDDIR:=.build_release
endif
```

do not use `find` to list files, better declare files explicitly

```
PROGS:=\
    prog0   \
    prog1   \

CPP_SRC:=\
    spam    \
    eggs    \

CPP_SRC_TEST:=\
    spam_test   \
    eggs_test   \
```

split off link targets, so only the target is created in a rule:

```
PROG_LINKS:=$(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/, $(PROGS))

PROGS:=$(PROGS:=.bin)
PROGS:=$(PROGS:%=$(BUILDDIR)/%)

CPP_SRC:=$(CPP_SRC:%=src/%.cpp)
CPP_OBJ:=$(CPP_SRC:src/%.cpp=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)

LIB:=$(BUILDDIR)/libspatialDecisionMaking.so

PROGS_TEST:=$(CPP_SRC_TEST:%=$(BUILDDIR)/test/%.bin)

PROGS_TEST_LINKS:=$(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/test, $(CPP_SRC_TEST))

## options

CC=g++-4.9
```

you are confusing `CPP_FLAGS` and `LD_FLAGS`, I put correct flags in each
also, your method of finding your shared library, is too complicated, I made it simple

```
CPP_FLAGS:= -std=c++11 -Isrc -fPIC -fopenmp

ifdef DEBUG
CPP_FLAGS+= -ggdb
else
CPP_FLAGS+= -O3
endif

LD_FLAGS:= -L$(BUILDDIR) -lgsl -larmadillo

## rules
```

you have too many dependencies - list only those that are conceptually needed for the target at hand, and recurse

```
all: | $(PROGS) $(PROG_LINKS) build

test: | $(PROGS_TEST) $(PROGS_TEST_LINKS) build
```

link file does not depend on the link target in any way

in your case, it depends on the value of `DEBUG` really, but like I said above, it is not super-easy to implement that, so I skipped it here and have a phony instead, which relinks all the time

```
.PHONY: build
build:
    ln -srf $(BUILDDIR) $@
```

this is the best way to handle directory creation

```
%/.:
    mkdir -p $(@D)
```

unfortunately, this is needed, because `mkdir -p` is not re-entrant and subject to race conditions

```
$(BUILDDIR)/test/.: | $(BUILDDIR)/.

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(PROGS_TEST_LINKS) $(PROG_LINKS): %: | %.bin
    ln -sr $| $@
```

all non-trivial recipes should depend on this makefile, change `Makefile` to whatever is correct (there is a more complicated way, to handle this automatically)

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.bin: src/%.cpp $(LIB) Makefile | $$(@D)/.
    $(CC) $(CPP_FLAGS) -o $@ $< $(LD_FLAGS) $(LIB)

$(LIB): $(CPP_OBJ) Makefile | $$(@D)/.
    $(CC) $(CPP_FLAGS) -o $@ $(CPP_OBJ) $(LD_FLAGS) -shared
```

this is the most efficient way to handle "automatic" dependency generation - it invokes the preprocessor only once, not twice as in your original makefile

I put this in quotes, because the whole method of automatic dependencies, is subtly flawed and cannot work in all cases - but in your simple case it is very unlikely you will run into that subtle flaw

Yes I am violating the good practice I mentioned above - only target created in rule.  If one understands what a good practice is for, and still thinks better to violate it, then OK.

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: src/%.cpp Makefile | $$(@D)/.
    $(CC) $(CPP_FLAGS) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@ $(LD_FLAGS)



# include dependencies
-include $(CPP_OBJ:%.o=%.d)

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILDDIR)
```

Comment: Mark, first off.  Wow.  Thank you for putting in so much time.  I was actually about to sit down and set up a MCVE when I logged on and saw your answer.  A few questions if I may.  1) What do you mean by "split off link targets to have one target per rule"?  Before the executable without a `.bin` extension was always linked and wasn't a "target" by Make's definition.  Are you saying to make those a target themselves? 2) Why does build need to be a phony target?  3) Is `$$` in the last few recipes related to the `.SECONDEXPANSION`?  I've never used this before, so I'm reading up on this now.

Comment: This has been extremely helpful.  I will be reading through this multiple times over the next few days to figure out exactly what your changes accomplish.  I have a lot to learn!

Comment: Since I posted this, I added `ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)` around the `-include` statement for the dependency files.  Without this, the recipes for `$(BUILDDIR)/%.o` are executed when running `make clean`.  After the objects are build, then the directory is removed.  Lots of wasted computation.  Does this happen with you as well?  I'm still seeing this behavior with the above changes if I don't check the goals for `clean`.

Comment: @nick 1. "split off" - you hand both `prog.bin` and `prog` which links to it, together made in one recipe, best practice is, make one target in one recipe, so I split off `prog` target into its own recipe

Comment: @nick build has to be redone when you change the value of DEBUG.  There is no simple way to do this, other than to always redo it, regardless of DEBUG.  There is a way to "depend" on DEBUG but it is a hack, I pointed you to my answer.

Comment: @nick 3. `SECONDEXPANSION` is for the `$$(@D)/.`, it is basically parsing again the makefile fragment below `SECONDEXPANSION`.  First time parse, establishes what `@D` is and escapes one `$`, then second, evaluates `$(@D)`.

Comment: @nick oh I see, if you build with one value of `DEBUG` and then you clean with a different value, then there is a problem.  You are probably doing `make clean`, where you should be doing `make DEBUG= clean` or `make DEBUG=y clean`.  Still, the user should not be forced to remember what the last value of `DEBUG` was.  Let me fix this, hold on.

Comment: @nick OK, I see - the line `%.d: %.o ;` is brain-dead, removed it.  This kind of line, is useful, but not in this situation, I included it as I normally would, without thinking.  Now you don't need any `ifneq $(MAKECMDGOALS)...`

Comment: Ah, that did it!  Well with your explanations, I understand each piece individually, but I will need to comb through this many more times before I completely comprehend the entire setup.  The biggest thing I need to do is understand why my previous setup didn't work.  Thank you for all the help.  I really appreciate it.  I will mark this as solved.

Comment: Also, to respond to your comment, the `-r` in the `ln` commands resolves relative paths.  Without it I was having issues with broken links due to not using absolute paths.

Comment: @nick yea, sorry I did not answer the question of 'why precisely did not work'.  A lot of times, if the question is not minimal, it is easier to just redo the whole thing, and then, usually the problem "magically" disappears.

Comment: @nick yes I put `-r` back in, looks like I do not have the latest version of `ln`

Answer (score 0):

The .d, .o, and .bin files logically depend on `$(BUILDDIR)`, so tell make that's the case

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.d: src/%.cpp | $(BUILDDIR)
```

Comment: This seems to be working.  Though now it runs the recipe for `$(BUILDDIR)` rule multiple times since the time stamp is constantly changing.  Not a big issue, just seems like something else is wrong.  I will work on a MCVE as recommended by Leffler in the question comments.

Comment: @nick You need to make it an order-only dependency wherever you want to use it.